# Не вызывается mousePressEvent в QGraphicsRectItem

Tags: c++, qt, события

Есть у меня класс `LifeView`, унаследованный от `QGraphicsView` для отрисовки сцены `LifeScene` (унаследованная от `QGraphicsScene`). 
На сцене изображаются элементы `LifeCell` (унаследованные от `QGraphicsRectItem`).

В `LifeCell` есть переопределенный метод обработки нажатия мыши

```
void LifeCell::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Если клетка живая была до нажатия, то перекрашиваем и делаем её мертвой
    changeStatus((currentStatus == C_ALIVE) ? C_DIED : C_ALIVE);
    qDebug() << "LifeCell: pressed";
    QGraphicsRectItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

Все элементы `LifeCell` у меня находятся в `QGraphicsItemGroup`.

Но в выводе приложения только такое:

```
LifeView: pressed
```

Хотя, по идее должно быть также:

```
LifeCell: pressed
```

Окей, пробовал сделать так, как написано в интернете:

```
void LifeView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "LifeView: pressed";
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
    event->accept();
}
```

В LifeView добавил такую строчку:

```
this->setMouseTracking(true);
```

Ничего не поменялось. Что я не так делаю?

**upd** Добавление в группу происходит у меня так.

```
m_itemGroup = new QGraphicsItemGroup();
    this->addItem(m_itemGroup);

    LifeCell    *pCell  = nullptr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
        {
            QRectF  rect;

            // Вычисление координат клетки
            qreal x  = j * cellSize;
            qreal y  = i * cellSize;

            rect.setX(x);               rect.setY(y);
            rect.setWidth(cellSize);    rect.setHeight(cellSize);

            pCell   = new LifeCell(rect);

            m_itemGroup->addToGroup(pCell);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, проблема в наличии группы. Вот минимальный пример, если заменить добавление объекта на добавление через группу (строка с маркером 1), `Item` перестает принимать событие.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class View : public QGraphicsView
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug()<<"VIEW CLICKED";
        QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
};

class Item : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug()<<"ITEM CLICKED";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Item *item = new Item;
    item->setRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
    QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 100, 100);
//    scene.createItemGroup(QList<QGraphicsItem *>() << item);  //[1]
    scene.addItem(item);    //[2]

    View view;
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

---

Для решения проблемы можно не убирать группу, достаточно вызвать для группы `setHandlesChildEvents(false)`, в этом случае обработка событий будет производиться не группой, а самими дочерними элементами.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Тогда как удобно расположить объекты? Может, каждый объект по отдельности добавлять по одному на сцену?

Comment: Если не требуется никаких манипуляций с группой (перемещение всех объектов одним махом, или там изменение размера), то я бы разместил все просто на сцене, группа в этом случае не нужна

Comment: Хорошо, а если мне надо будет удаление организовать (в процессе, количество клеток может меняться пользователем)? У меня поле, допустим, 50х20 и пользователь изменил размер на 40х30. Надо как-то манипулировать этими клетками, только я не знаю как. Может, элементы сначала в список закинуть, а потом на сцену?

Comment: Так есть же QGraphicsScene::clear(), и не надо ручками удалять каждый из элементов. Другое дело, как вы планируете менять состояние элемента при смене состояния клетки? Не чистить же сцену и добавлять элементы заново. Оптимально наверное будет сохранить элементы в двухмерный массив размера аналогичного размеру матрицы и обновлять состояние элемента по индексу. Правда по обоим этим вопросам группа вам ничем не поможет.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, добавил решение, не требующее убирать группы

Comment: спасибо. Заработало